# Is there a way to read CPU temps on Android 9+ under root?

Tags: root-access, cpu

Given the fact I have rooted device, is there a way to get that data? Raw or w/ tools.

P.S. I was looking around for a build of `htop` with cpu thermals but I dont think there is any compatible for Android.

Comment: Have you checked the answers of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771070/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature?

Comment: Try this: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/246774/96277

Comment: @Firelord Sadly, no, literally 0 output even though `dumpsys -l` shows it in the service list

Comment: Try: `grep . /sys/class/hwmon/*/{name,temp*_input}` and `for zone in /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*; do echo "$(cat $zone/type) $(cat $zone/temp)"; done | sort -rnk2 | awk '{printf "%-30s%.1f\n",$1,$2/1000}'`. These should work on all Linux systems.

Comment: https://github.com/SmartPack/SmartPack-Kernel-Manager/releases/download/v17.2/com.smartpack.kernelmanager-v17.2-fdroid-release.apk

Comment: @IrfanLatif Which one is the CPU (cores) though? There are like 30-40 zones

Comment: Unfortunately exact names of thermal sensors depend on hardware vendors. But most of the thermal zones are around CPUs, like inside / outside, below / above, right / left etc. And most of them have a word like "cpu" or "core" in their name. Some others include GPU, power adapter, battery etc. Usually it's evident from their names. A simple approach is to put a load on all CPU cores and watch which zones show quick arise in temperature. Keep watching them in future and ignore the others in your shell command.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks.