# Which folder contains the temperature sensor output for the CPU in /sys/devices/virtual/thermal?

Tags: cpu, temperature

`/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp` shows 37°C (37000 millicelcius) no matter what the actual temperature is. The device is Moto G32, Android 12, not rooted. Using `cat` on Termux to view the temperature.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. There is a similar question that may help: [How do I get the temperature of my phone via ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/246774/44325). While the question mentioned ADB, the underlying command `dumpsys thermalservice` should be able to be called directly from Termux. Let us know if it helps. Otherwise, is there a requirement to get the value from that folder specifically?

Comment: While following the advice of Andrew make sure you give Termux the DUMP permission to access dumps from system services and then call dumpsys by its absolute path. Here's how: `adb shell pm grant com.termux android.permission.dump`; Then in your Termux environment, run `/system/bin/dumpsys thermalservice`

Comment: I'm currently away from my pc but I'll try this out and update